# If lamb shift is really due to the effect caused by virtual particles how come it only affect 1 orbital?

Tags: electrons, virtual-particles, lamb-shift

I was watching a video explaining virtual particle can be drawn to the positively charged necleus which explain why there is a tiny step between the higher energy level and ground state, but I'm not convinced as to why it doesn't affect all other energy levels?

Comment: The Lamb shift does affect other orbitals - it just does so at higher orders of perturbation theory. There are more details at [Why is the energy of $2s_{1/2}$ greater than the energy of $2p_{1/2}$ after the Lamb shift is taken into account?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429690/why-is-the-energy-of-2s-1-2-greater-than-the-energy-of-2p-1-2-after-the).

Comment: "lambshift" ... ?

Comment: @my2cts Yes that is a typo, but I'm sure you know what they mean.

Comment: @Aaron Steven For a brief moment I believed that they mistake "Willis Eugene Lamb Jr. (July 12, 1913 – May 15, 2008) [ ] an American physicist who won the Nobel Prize in Physics in 1955 "for his discoveries concerning the fine structure of the hydrogen spectrum.",  for _livestock_.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willis_Lamb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lamb Shift will certainly contain contributions from all energy levels in an atomic system (including the non-bound ones), but basic perturbation theory will tell you that the contribution from higher energy levels will be negligible compared to the next-highest-level contribution (which is already quite small).