# Is the $2p\rightarrow2s$ transition possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

Selection rules in one electron atoms are:

1. $\Delta n=$ any
2. $\Delta l=\pm1$
3. $\Delta m_l=0,\pm1$
4. $\Delta s=0$
5. Parity must change

Under strong spin orbit interaction:

6. $\Delta j=0,\pm 1$, but $j=0\nRightarrow\: j'=0 $
7. $\Delta m_j=0,\pm1$

In my notes, it states that while considering a $\rm H$ atom in the $2p$ state with $m_l=0$, the only possible decay is to the $1s$ ground state with $m_l=0$. This implies that the $2p\rightarrow2s$ transition is *not* possible but upon looking at the selection rules, I can't find anything wrong with it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The transition is possible, though it's important to note that the energy ordering is opposite to what you seem to think it is - the $2s$ energy is higher than the $2p$ energy. Moreover, this energy difference is absolutely tiny - either $4\:\rm \mu eV$ or $50 \:\rm \mu eV$, depending on the total angular momentum in the $2p$ state, corresponding to wavelengths of order $30\:\rm cm$ and $3\:\rm cm$ (and therefore frequencies of order $970\:\rm MHz$ and $12\:\rm GHz$), respectively. (For more details about this splitting see e.g. my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429690/why-is-the-energy-of-2s-1-2-greater-than-the-energy-of-2p-1-2-after-the).)

Still if you have a good enough state-preparation procedure and a stable enough microwave source, probably together with a pretty fancy atomic-beam apparatus, you should be able to observe the transition.

The lines are listed in the [NIST ASD](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html) database - it's a good exercise to learn to use it so that you can find the states, the transitions, and the listed references to experimental observations of all the lines involved.

Answer (score 4):

The story is more complicated. There are three states, $^2S_{1/2}$, $^2P_{1/2}$ and $^2P_{3/2}$. These are degenerate in the Schrödinger solution of the hydrogen atom. The Dirac equation shifts the $^2P_{3/2}$ and leaves  the $^2S_{1/2}$ and $^2P_{1/2}$ degenerate. QED radiative corrections lift this degeneracy by a small amount of about 1 GHz, the famous Lamb shift, which is an important precision test of QED. Willis Lamb received the Nobel prize in 1955 for its experimental determination in 1947.

Answer (score 1):

I will narrow the scope of the question as follows: **is the transition with spontaneous emission of a photon between the Lamb split levels (i.e. $2S_{1/2}→2P_{1/2}$) forbidden by the dipole selection rules?** No, it is allowed. However the spontaneous emission rate, which is $\sim f^3$, where $f$ is the transition frequency ($\sim 1\rm GHz$ in this case), is much lower than would be for a typical visible spectrum transition ($f\sim 10^{15}\rm Hz$, emission rates$\sim 10^8\rm s^{-1}$). Since on the other hand $2S_{1/2}→1S_{1/2}$ is forbidden by the parity selection rule, the decay rate of $2S_{1/2}$ ends up being very low: $8 \rm s^{-1}$, leading to this state being considered metastable.